# Swift MAC app failed to laucnh after being patched by IDA

Tags: swift, assembly, x86-64, disassembly, ida

I'm new to reverse engineering on Apple Devices and i have developed a very very simple crack me for learning purposes! everything works fine, but when i open my binary file in IDA and change the condition instruction, and apply the patch, my app starts to failing on launch!

there are 2 ways i can crack the code, first by changing the condition statement from JNZ to JZ, and the other way NOP the JMP function below the JNZ instruction.

```
__text:0000000100001387                 mov     rdi, [rbp+var_68]
__text:000000010000138B                 call    _objc_release
__text:0000000100001390                 mov     al, [rbp+var_81]
__text:0000000100001396                 test    al, 1
__text:0000000100001398                 jnz     short loc_10000139F// Goes for Correct condition
__text:000000010000139A                 jmp     loc_100001475 //goes for incorrect condition
```

in C and other languages which i have experience in reverse engineering, these solutions would work.does any one have any clue what is going here?

### Edit

here is my crack me code in swift!

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBAction func btn(_ sender: Any) {

        if(input.stringValue == "!@#><1234")
        {
            let box = NSAlert()
            box.alertStyle = .informational
            box.messageText = "Cool!"
            box.runModal()
        }else{
            let box = NSAlert()
            box.alertStyle = .critical
            box.messageText = "Not Cool!"
            box.runModal()
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var input: NSTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {

        }
    }
}
```

### SOLUTION

it was a code signing problem within its binary. i think when we apply a patch and change the binary, OS doesn't allow the app to be executed. so i just resigned my app and now it is cracked and working.

Comment: Please don't post links to external file hosters.  All questions on Stack Overflow must be self-contained.  Instead, post the source code of your application or a [MCVE] into the question.

Comment: @fuz Sorry, edited

Comment: Now your question contains no project at all and is impossible to reproduce.  Do as a I said before and attach a [MCVE] (with a focus on *reproducible*).

Comment: @sci3nt15t Please post the solution as an answer, not as a part of your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION

it was a code signing problem within its binary. i think when we apply a patch and change the binary, OS doesn't allow the app to be executed. so i just resigned my app and now it is cracked and working.